# Can Arduino ESP8266 sscanf handle %lld?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, scanf

I'm having an issue with Arduino ESP8266 and the `sscanf` function. I'm trying to parse a 64 bit integer from the string I received from the serial port like this:

```cpp
int64_t temp_freq = 0;
sscanf(buffer, "FOUT = %lld Hz\r\n", &temp_freq);
```

EDIT: I also tried `"FOUT = %" SCNd64 " Hz\r\n", with the same result

I know I got the right string from the serial port, since my code which checks if I received that specific type of message is triggered and is running.

I can also confirm that %lld is working with `Serial.printf()`, so I would assumed it is implemented for `sscanf` as well.

However, if I have a value > 2^31 - 1 in the string, I get 2^31 - 1 written into my `int64_t` variable. So for example `"FOUT = 18010000000 Hz\r\n"` gives me 2,147,483,647 in my `int64_t` variable.

Am I using `sscanf` incorrectly, or is it simply not implemented correctly on the platform?

I am using the following as a workaround in the mean time:

```cpp
int64_t temp_freq = 0;
char temp_buf[30] = {0x00};
sscanf(buffer, "FOUT = %s Hz\r\n", &temp_buf);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_buf); ++i) {
  temp_freq *= 10;
  temp_freq += temp_buf[i] - '0';
}
```

But I'd like to rather have the standard way working and correct to save me having to maintain my hand-rolled solutions everywhere.

PS: I tagged as C++ and C, since it is technically C++ on Arduino, but the code I've written looks more like C and uses C's `sscanf` instead of `stringstream` or something similar from C++.

Comment: If you do `#include <sys/features.h>` and then do `printf("%s\n", _NEWLIB_VERSION)`, what does it output? Or `printf("%d\n", _WANT_IO_LONG_LONG)`.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", _NEWLIB_VERSION);` gives `2.2.0`. `printf("%s\n", _WANT_IO_LONG_LONG);` results in a compile error due to `_WANT_IO_LONG_LONG` not being declared in current scope.

Comment: Have you tried using `sscanf(buffer, "FOUT = %" SCNd64 " Hz\r\n", &temp_freq);` (you'll need to `#include <inttypes.h>`).

Comment: @AdrianMole I did, forgot to mention. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: If your library indeed doesn't support `%lld`, and if you decide to "roll your own", it might be easier to use hexadecimal rather than decimal.  In particular, if the sending side always sends exactly 16 hexadecimal digits, on the receiving side you could do something like `long hi, lo; sscanf(buffer, "FOUT = %8lx%8lx Hz\r\n", &hi, &lo)` followed by `temp_freq = (int64_t)hi << 32 | lo`.

Comment: @SteveSummit it would've been nice, but the sending side is human-facing, as well, and the humans reading it are probably going to be RF engineers, so not people that well versed in reading hex.

Comment: Why are you using `long long` for a frequency, though?  I would have thought `float` or `double` would be more appropriate.  (Do you really have frequencies greater than 2.15 GHz to handle, but as an integer?)

Comment: The full story: It is for a synth which can synthesize 10 MHz to 20 GHz. The ESP8266 is in a 4dSystems gen4-IoD display module. Their library use ints for displaying 7-segment LED digits on the screen, even if the digits has a decimal point. And the synth (which was developed previously already as a module to be controlled via a PC and serial port. We're adding the touch screen now to make it stand-alone) already outputs the frequency in the format I gave after a successful frequency change. I'd rather not muck with it too much.

Comment: Besides, the ESP doesn't have floating point hardware, so it slows to a chug if I use `float` or `double`. So I avoid it as far as possible.

Comment: @LouisCloete I was afraid it was something like that. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it simply not implemented correctly on the platform?

Your toolchain is using newlib as a C standard library implementation and most probably you are using it's nano version. Newlib-nano does not come with `long long` support in `printf/scanf` family functions.

You can:

- Use full newlib version instead of nano version. In case of `gcc` compiler do *not* pass `-specs=nano.specs` or `-lnano` to your compiler options.
- Use a different standard library or recompile newlib with the option enabled.
- Reimplement the needed functionality yourself.

Note that using `%lld` with `int64_t` may be technically wrong - you should use `SCNd64` from `inttypes.h`.

Comment: What's wrong with `%lld`?  Who says you have to use `SCNd64 `?

Comment: It's not wrong, just not as portable. On the specific chip I'm using `SCNd64 is probably defined as `%lld`, since `int64_t` is a typedef for `long long int`. `SCNd64` will do the right thing on all platforms with `int64_t`, not just on 32 bit platforms on which `int64_t` is a typedef for `long long int`.

Comment: @SteveSummit: `%lld` expects a `long long int`. `SCNd64` expects a `int64_t`. Using `%lld` to scan into a `uint64_t` is assuming that `long long int` and `int64_t` are identical on all platforms that piece of code will be running on, ever.